# PHPUnit - fixtures are too slow to load

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm facing a very strange problem when i'm launching my unit tests. When I launch my tests without coverage my fixtures seems to be loaded too slowly (my tests are doing before my fixture for this test is loaded). So i have failures.

When I launch with a coverage, or without coverage but with a sleep(1), (so my tests take a little bit more time) my fixtures are well loaded into my database.

Do you have any ideas of what's going on ?

Here is how I load my fixtures :

```
public function getDataSet()
  {
    // Load the fixture related to a test.
    $fixture = $this->getFixturePath('fixture' . ucfirst($this->getName(false)));
    if(file_exists($fixture))
    {
      return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet($fixture);
    }

    // Load the main fixture.
    if(file_exists($this->getFixturePath('fixture')))
    {
      return $this->createFlatXMLDataSet($this->getFixturePath('fixture'));
    }

    throw new Exception('Missing main fixture');
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: where do you call `getDataSet`?. In the `setUp()` ?

Comment: No I declare getDataSet in my class which extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase so it's called automatically.